# Touchscreen ELO(touch) not recognized on Lubuntu at startup

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen, xinput

I have added the following command to /etc/rc.local

```
/usr/bin/inputattach --daemon --always -elo /dev/ttyS4
```

but it is not loaded at startup. I have checked that the mode is supported and it works when I call it in lxterminal or when I enter sudo sh /etc/rc.local

When I add one of the following commands using mtouch or elo3b, it does work at startup (but the accuracy is really bad, even after executing calibrator):

```
/usr/bin/inputattach --daemon --always -mtouch /dev/ttyS4
/usr/bin/inputattach --daemon --always -elo3b /dev/ttyS4
```

What could be the reason -elo is not loaded at startup, where -elo3b and -mtouch are?

There is nothing in the logs that gives an error.

Alternatively, is there any other (easier) way of enabling the touchscreen on lubuntu? I only care if tap on the screen is working, not multi touch gestures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been looking for a solution for 3 days. Finally found it thanks to the sources below. For anybody who is facing a similar problem. You need to add the following rule to /lib/udev/rules.d/40-inputattach.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyS4", ACTION=="add|change", RUN+="/lib/udev/inputattach --elotouch /dev/%k"
```

http://who-t.blogspot.nl/2012/07/elographics-touchscreen-setup.html

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EloTouchScreen